# How to make continuous id numbering in a table?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm working on C# project using EF Core with Postgres database.
I need to send serialized data from a database to a message broker. Data will be sent every month at a certain time.
For example, there are 100 data records and they are sent today. These data records will have an **cID** (continuous ID) from 1 to 100. Next month, these 100 records will be sent again. But then the **cID** should start from 101 to 200.

This is how it should like

[image]

Here is an example model:

```
[Table("institutions")]
public partial class Institution
{
    public Institution()
    {
        InstitutionResources = new HashSet<InstitutionResource>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    [Column("phone")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Column("email_address")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(AddressId))]
    [InverseProperty("Institutions")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(InstitutionResource.Institution))]
    public virtual ICollection<InstitutionResource> InstitutionResources { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have just numbered the table:

```
 public List<InstitutionDataResult> FormInstitutionDataResult()
 {
     long cID = 1; // Here I want cID was continuous
     var institutions = _dbContext.Institutions
         .Select(s => new InstitutionDataResult
         {
             //CID = there should be an id
             Id = s.Id, // it is an id from the table
             NameKk = s.InstitutionResources.Where(l => l.LanguageId == 1).SingleOrDefault().Name,
             NameRu = s.InstitutionResources.Where(l => l.LanguageId == 2).SingleOrDefault().Name,
             Geoposition = s.Address.Geoposition.ToString(),
             Phone = s.Phone,
             Email = s.EmailAddress,
             Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
         }).ToList();
     // 
     foreach (var institution in institutions)
     {
         institution.CID = cID;
         cID++;
     }
     return crosswalks;
 }
```

And I was hinted that I can use postgres sequences, but I have no idea how to use them

Comment: If you have the keyword "sequence" already have you looked that up in the documentation?

Comment: Define cID as identity column? Get the last-used id first?

Comment: That requirement doesn't make sense to me. Is there a reason why the identical data should have a different id?

Comment: It also makes the api very feeble. What if you encounter an error and get out of sync with cIDs? What cID to start with if the backend is restarted? Which one if the client is restarted? How would you be able to find out? I, personally, consider that api fundamentally broken.

Comment: The fields of some records may change over time. Some records may be deleted or new records may be added. So amount of records may be changed

Comment: Then it makes even less sense.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to me that you should just add a date field and possibly an identifier that uniquely links the records to the source data. It's hard to tell what's best without knowing more details of this process.

Comment: Maybe I am thrown off by the name. Because obviously, it doesn't "identify" a record. I am guessing it's some internal requirement of the broker? Which would lead me to ask: does it really need to be consecutive? Or is it enough to have a number that is rising monotonically?

Comment: The institution table initially does not have a сID and is not associated with the table, cID will be needed when I form the data to send. And I need to somehow always get the next value in the program in order to continue numbering these records.

Answer (score 0):

By default in entity framework, a `long Id` property will be interpreted as the primary auto incrementing key. A value of zero is interpreted as a new object that will have a new id assigned when the object is saved.

You can specify specific Ids manually, but this can mess with the internal sequence of the database if you are not careful.

But you should never assume anything specific about the auto-generated values, other than being unique, and possibly monotonically increasing with time. If you need the Ids to have some special relation, like batch 1 having 1-100, and batch 2 having 101-200, you are probably better of expressing this relation explicitly, for example by having an separate Id and BatchId fields. You can combine there into a composite key if needed. I'm no database expert, but I would probably use an internal primary auto incrementing key, and use (composite) surrogate key(s) for any data from external sources. Just make sure to clearly label columns, so you are not mixing up Ids that are used in different contexts.